# Spliting string twice with 2 separators in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Let's say I need to split the string `a.b.c.d#.e.f.g.h#.i.j.k.l` with separator as # and then ".".

```
str = a.b.c.d#.e.f.g.h#.i.j.k.l

res = str.split("#")
```

`res[0]` will store `a.b.c.d` when I use split for the 1st time .
I need to split this again and save the data.

can anyone help ?

Comment: Just split it again? Also, where do you want to "save" this data?

Comment: Please give an example and your expected output. It is not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to split again, you just do it.

Comment: What's the problem with using a loop after the first `.split()`?

Answer (score 6):

I think the simplest way to do it is using a regex:

```
    var str = "a.b.c.d#.e.f.g.h#.i.j.k.l";

    var res = str.split(/[.#]/);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a bit old, but came across it, and fell like there was a better, perhaps more modern, solution. Excluding comments, this is a neat solution to this problem, and is a bit more flexible. It uses the `reduce` prototype, which works pretty well. This can be modified to output an object with key/value pairs as well.

```js
const input = 'a.b.c#.e.f.g#.h.i.j'
const firstDelimiter = '#';
const secondDelimiter = '.';

// This will prevent sub arrays from containing empty values, i.e. ['','e','f','g']
const cleanInput = input.replace(/#./g, '#');

//First split by the firstDelimiter
const output = cleanInput.split(firstDelimiter).reduce( (newArr, element, i) => {
  // By this point, you will have an array like ['a.b.c', 'e.f.g', 'h.i.j']
  // Each element is passed into the callback, into the element variable
  let subArr = element.split(secondDelimiter); // split that element by the second delimiter, created another array like ['a', 'b', 'c'], etc.
  console.log(i, newArr)
  // newArr is the accumulator, and will maintain it's values
  newArr[i] = subArr;

  return newArr;

}, []); //It's important to include the [] for the initial value of the accumulator

console.log('final:', output);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I may, if you have to split a `string` with character `a` then character `b`, the simplest in my mind would be : `string.split('a').join('b').split('b')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split by '#' and then for each item split by '.'

Input:`'a.b.c.d#.e.f.g.h#.i.j.k'`

Output:`[ a b c d e f g h i j k]`

```
var str = 'a.b.c.d#.e.f.g.h#.i.j.k.l';
        var ar = [];
        var sp = str.split('#');
        for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
            var sub = sp[i].split('.');
            for (var j = 0; j < sub.length; j++) {
                ar.push(sub[j]);
            }
        }
        alert(ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I made that splits an array:

```
function splitArray(array, delimiter) {
    let returnValue = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i].split(delimiter);
        array[i].forEach(elem => {
            returnValue.push(elem);
        });
    };
        return returnValue;
};
```

In your case, use it like this:

```
str = "a.b.c.d#.e.f.g.h#.i.j.k.l";
console.log( splitArray (str.split ("#"), "." ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

To split string with multiple separators you can use regex:

```
str.split(/STR_1|STR_2|STR_N/);
```

Make sure that STR does not contains regexp operational characters, if it is, add '\' before them

Answer (score -1):

You can use the explode function similar to php

```
//   example 1: explode(' ', 'Kevin van Zonneveld');
//   returns 1: {0: 'Kevin', 1: 'van', 2: 'Zonneveld'}

function explode(delimiter, string, limit) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/explode/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)

  if (arguments.length < 2 || typeof delimiter === 'undefined' || typeof string === 'undefined') return null;
  if (delimiter === '' || delimiter === false || delimiter === null) return false;
  if (typeof delimiter === 'function' || typeof delimiter === 'object' || typeof string === 'function' || typeof string ===
    'object') {
    return {
      0: ''
    };
  }
  if (delimiter === true) delimiter = '1';

  // Here we go...
  delimiter += '';
  string += '';

  var s = string.split(delimiter);

  if (typeof limit === 'undefined') return s;

  // Support for limit
  if (limit === 0) limit = 1;

  // Positive limit
  if (limit > 0) {
    if (limit >= s.length) return s;
    return s.slice(0, limit - 1)
      .concat([s.slice(limit - 1)
        .join(delimiter)
      ]);
  }

  // Negative limit
  if (-limit >= s.length) return [];

  s.splice(s.length + limit);
  return s;
}
```

For more functions visit http://phpjs.org/

Comment: Just FYI for the future, it's usually better to edit your existing answer and then undelete it instead of providing two answers (one deleted, one not), unless your answers are completely unrelated.